# ComboBox with data binding and extra value

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a dataset with different values. I would like to implement a combobox that filters this data. In application model I have the range of possible values but besides that I want to add extra "Any" field. Is that possible when using DataBinding?

The question is only about how to properly fill the combobox with data, assuming that this data is dynamic (besites special Any entry).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new 'Any' row to your dataset in code. I usually do it with an ID of -1

Comment: This value is only allowed in the combobox, and the rest of application is rather unaware of such value. There's no other way?

Comment: Add the row to the dataset just on the form using the combo box